# Error when building older solution in VS2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to build a solution created in VS2003 using VS2013 but I get the following error:

> Error 1   The command "call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>    8\Common7\Tools\Bin\mt.exe" 
>        -manifest "C:\Users\Nikolay\Desktop\xxx\xxx\xx.exe.manifest" 
>        –outputresource:"C:\Users\Nikolay\Desktop\xx\xx\bin\Debug\xx.exe";
>        #1" exited with code 1.    xx

I'm running windows 10

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: 8 is the version number of Visual Studio 2003. I suspect the solution contains build events that target 2003 tools. Even if the tools exist on the machine (ie you have VS 2003 installed), using them in a 2013 solution can lead to other problems. You should check all build events for calls to the old tools and replace them with the equivalent tools for 2013

Comment: Great, turns out there are post build events for the solution. I haven't used those before so I didn't know that they exist as a problem. I removed the events and the solution builds and runs as expected on VS2013. 

You should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are post build events for the solution. I haven't used those before so I didn't know that they exist as a problem. I removed the events and the solution builds and runs as expected on VS2013.